# React css using ref instead of id

Tags: reactjs

**Backstory**

Normally I would use an `id` for to manipulate an elements default styling

```
html:
    <div id="my-div"></div>
    
stylesheet:
    #my-div { background: white }
```

In react it seems like `id`s are out and `ref`s are in yet I don't see much info for doing styling with refs.

```
html:
    <div ref="my-div"></div>

stylesheet:
    ???
```

**Question**

How can I edit an element's style using refs in a stylesheet?

## ** EDIT **

This post was made some time ago. I have since discovered refs are for internal/virtual  element tracking. I've also cut out id's for my singleton elements as I reserve ids as a final option for css purposes eg. when there are multiple competing class styles, id will take charge.

Comment: you can use `id`s.

Comment: you can check it through Dev Tools: `ref` attribute is sooooo internal for React that it does not come into DOM at all. So it's technically impossible to refer that in CSS even if you use old-school "string ref". You should modify component themselves by adding `id`, `className` or any other attribute to be able referencing that in CSS

Comment: No, you can't edit an element's style using `ref` in a stylesheet. As `ref` is  not accessible in the DOM. so you can't even use attribute selector `[attr=value]` to style the element. so simply use `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need refs to style a div, you can still use ids or classes!

Read about refs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Read about styling your components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could just create CSS style rules and assign the appropriate rules to the semantic elements constituting your `React` component as necessary?

For example:

**React code:**

```
<div className="custom">
  <p>My test paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Rules:**

```
.custom {
  // add your styling here
}
```

Instead of the `class` keyword as in HTML it's `className` in React since in React you can't use any `JavaScript` specific language keywords.

Hopefully that helps!